# Saving a child shouldn't cause an insertion of a row into parent table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys, spring-data-jpa

I have a a parent-child relationship between two entities established using `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne`. The child uses parent's id as a foreign key and a part of composite primary key. It seems quite logical to me that persisting an instance of the child class whose parent is not persisted violates foreign key constraints. I expected an exception, but I've noticed that saving child causes inserting parent object into database, too. How can I prevent this?

Here's the parent class:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<OneTimeKey> preKeys;

    @Lob
    private byte[] key;

    public User(byte[] key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

}
```

The child class:

```
public class KeyId implements Serializable {

    long owner;
    long keyId;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(KeyId.class)
public class OneTimeKey {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private User owner;

    @Id
    private long keyId;

    @Lob
    private byte[] key;

    public OneTimeKey(User owner, long keyId, byte[] key) {
        this.owner = owner;
        this.keyId = keyId;
        this.key = key;
    }

}
```

And here's the test method that fails:

```
@Test
public void givenUserDoesntExistShouldNotPersist() {

    User testUser = new User("owner".getBytes());
    OneTimeKey preKey = new OneTimeKey(testUser, 0, "test".getBytes());
    oneTimeKeyRepository.saveAndFlush(preKey);
    OneTimeKey result = oneTimeKeyRepository.findOne(new KeyId(1, 0));
    assertNull(result);

}
```

Logs show that calling saveAndFlush() causes this:

```
Hibernate: insert into User (key, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into OneTimeKey (key, keyId, owner_id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

I've tried establishing unidirectional relationship using `@JoinColumn` but it doesn't help.

Comment: Under what circumstances would you want to disable it? You are guaranteed an error so seems kind of pointless.

Comment: Define the relationship with a proper cascadeType... You can specify which operations shall be propagated...

Comment: @AndreasAumayr Disabling cascade persist and cascade merge didn't work.

Comment: @AlanHay Security reasons. Moreover, let's consider a long chain of entities, in which each consecutive entity takes foreign key from the previous one. Now, if we want to save an instance of entity from the end of the chain, it will cause cascade insert to consecutive tables. However, if an object from the middle of the chain failed to persist, some unnecessary records would remain in the database.

Comment: ?? Isn't that what transactions are for?